Decrypting EC PEM Key in Swift
I've been trying to create an SEC key from my pem string (ive checked its a valid key), but i keep coming across the same errors and im not sure what to do:
import XCTest
import Foundation
import Security

final class reader_iOSTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func createKey() -> SecKey? {
        let pemKey = """
        EC-Parameters: (256 bit)
        -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
        MHcCAQEEIJnIOLJS0kWnbMuPnGhgj1a5kOrmts0zUJ3s0yS1ZfOwoAoGCCqGSM49
        AwEHoUQDQgAE2Jv2ux+edHPzseGnYzwwF+kAAIZNC7/ZhDSHvsGHoqSSJN4SwfQn
        ItXimSk+9AUCVzA3JPg7BoorjJxHNMRyzA==
        -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
        """
        
        // Extract the base64 encoded string
        let base64String = pemKey
            .split(separator: "\n")
            .filter { line in
                !line.contains("BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY") && !line.contains("END EC PRIVATE KEY") && !line.contains("EC-Parameters")
            }
            .joined()
        
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else {
            print("Error: Data is not valid base64")
            return nil
        }
        
        print("Base64 Data: \(data.base64EncodedString())") // Debug print
        
        // Define attributes for the private key
        let attributes: [String: Any] = [
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
            kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate
        ]
        
        print("Attributes: \(attributes)") // Debug print
        
        // Create the SecKey
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &error) else {
            if let error = error?.takeRetainedValue() {
                print("Error creating SecKey: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        return key
    }
    
    func testPrivateKey() {
        let privateKey = createKey()
        XCTAssertNotNil(privateKey, "Failed to decode private key")
    }
}

output:
Attributes: ["type": 73, "kcls": 1]
2024-05-17 10:56:17.206730+0100 reader-iOS[2459:1010122] [seckey] SecKeyCreate init(ECPrivateKey) failed: -50
Error creating SecKey: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "EC private key creation from data failed" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=EC private key creation from data failed}
/Users/tomrowbotham/Documents/Documents - Tom’s MacBook Pro/ios/reader-iOS/reader-iOSTests/reader_iOSTests.swift:54: error: -[reader_iOSTests.reader_iOSTests testPrivateKey] : XCTAssertNotNil failed - Failed to decode private key

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I have an equivalent working version? I've verified the key is correct
Expecting to create an SECKey so that I can perform crpytography actions. But instead it fails with
2024-05-17 10:56:17.206730+0100 reader-iOS[2459:1010122] [seckey] SecKeyCreate init(ECPrivateKey) failed: -50
Error creating SecKey: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "EC private key creation from data failed" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=EC private key creation from data failed}


The EC parameters you are providing is not something the SecKey can use out of the box if at all. Additionally, the EC parameters you provide are in a compressed format if I look correctly, but don't quote me on that. In order to create the SecKeyCreateWithData it's important to understand what data is required. I quote the documentation:

For an elliptic curve public key, the format follows the ANSI X9.63 standard using a byte string of 04 || X || Y. For an elliptic curve private key, the output is formatted as the public key concatenated with the big endian encoding of the secret scalar, or 04 || X || Y || K. All of these representations use constant size integers, including leading zeros as needed.

Thus, it's best you convert your key in such a way that it has the format as requested by Apple.
What I can tell from the data you provided, is that this is a P-256 key and there's just one integer provided that we can use. I've extracted the key data using ASN.1 decoding and ended up with this:
// 04 = octet, 20 = 32 bytes
leftover bytes is the 32 byte integer (likely the K parameter of the private key)
04 20 99C838B252D245A76CCB8F9C68608F56B990EAE6B6CD33509DECD324B565F3B0
// The useful data therefor are only the 32 bytes at the end, which in base64 is
mcg4slLSRadsy4+caGCPVrmQ6ua2zTNQnezTJLVl87A=

This value can be used in CryptoKit
import CryptoKit

let bytes = Data(base64Encoded: "mcg4slLSRadsy4+caGCPVrmQ6ua2zTNQnezTJLVl87A=")!
let privateKey = try! P256.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey(rawRepresentation: bytes)
// Or if you want to use it for signing
let privateKey = try! P256.Signing.PrivateKey(rawRepresentation: bytes)

// You can convert that key to a SecKey if you wish to do so
let parameters: [CFString: Any] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
    kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 256
]
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKey.x963Representation as CFData, parameters as CFDictionary, &error)

So to summarise:

Alter your data to be conform the requested spec (X9.63 format, 04 || X || Y || K), that would be the easiest
Alternatively, extract the private key value and use CryptoKit to load the private key and convert that key into a SecKey


Thanks so much Bram! This has helped so much

@TomRowbotham be aware that you have shared a private key just now and I advise you to no longer use it in production. Glad I could help thus far

yep thanks, this private key isnt used :)
